# flutter Handling empty api data

Tags: flutter

I'm working with the Movie API.

I want to implement an application that recommends movies at random.

When the recommend button is clicked, it randomly requests a MovieID value through a math function.

Random movieId = Random(). nextInt(100000) +1;

For example, I know how to return a blank screen if the value returned above is 4586 but there is no 4586 in the api data.

I don't want a blank screen

I want to know how to iterate through the data in the api until it finds a value.

When you click the recommend button
I wish I could see the movie

Thank you. :)

- add info

- repo
  [image]
- provider

[image]

- movieWidget

[image]

Comment: You can first get the API endpoint that lists IDs of all the available movies and then you can return a random ID from that list to the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<int> movieIds = [12348,89577,85948,55536]; // all movies in API
  int movieId = Random(). nextInt(100000) +1;
  print("generated id: $movieId");
  int movieIndex = movieIds.indexWhere((id) => id == movieId); // returns -1 if id not found in list
  movieIndex != -1 ? print("do something for index: $movieIndex") : print("not found");
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am getting the id values ​​of api data one by one in int type. Do you know how to group all these id values ​​into a list type?

Comment: I added a picture to the question.

Comment: just create an empty list and add them to it, as simple as that.